# smart app banner in magento mobile site for android and ios

Tags: android, magento, mobile, deep-linking, smartbanner

Help me with creating the smart app banner for android and ios in magento mobile server. Basically it would function the way if the customer did not have the app in their device the banner which would appear at the top gives the option to download it and if the app is already installed in the device it must give an option to open the app. I have found few links for smart app banner and deep links which might help to achieve this, but the real problem lies is how to implement those in a magento site. Any help appreciated.
*P.S. I am new to magento.*

Answer (score 0):

For iphone it is pretty simple. You need to grab your unique app id from itunes connect and place it in a meta tag in the head section of Magento. It looks like this.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID"/>
```

Replace 'myAppStoreID' with your id and it should work. For android it is a little trickier. There are javascript examples out there but you will have to google it.